# "Subscribe to more newsletters" - but I'm not subscribed to those I see!

Tags: bug, network-profile, subscription

When viewing the network profile of a different user, we see such a thing:

> [image]

The "Subscribe to more newsletters" link makes perfect sense when viewing my own profile, but I don't think it should be there when viewing different profile, or when not logged in.